# Counting items from Map having Set as value

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a list of items as below

```
List<SomeModel> smList = new ArrayList<>();

    smList.add(new SomeModel(1L,6.0f));//id = 1L and capacity = 6.0f
    smList.add(new SomeModel(2L,7.0f));
    smList.add(new SomeModel(3L,7.0f));
    smList.add(new SomeModel(4L,7.0f));
```

Now I am converting this list into

```
Map<Float, Set<Long>> complexList = new HashMap<>();
        complexList = smList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(SomeModel::getCapacity,
                Collectors.mapping(SomeModel::getId, Collectors.toSet())));
```

here complexList
gives output as

```
7.0=[2, 3, 4]
6.0=[1]
```

Now I need to count number of values for each "capacity" giving output as

```
7.0=3
6.0=1
```

I tried

```
Map<Float, Long> complexCount = complexList.entrySet().stream().
                collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey, 
                        Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.counting())));
        complexCount.forEach((k,v)->System.out.println(k+"="+v));
```

and it outputs

```
6.0=1
7.0=1
```

I must be mistaking in understanding streams or not be using right methods. Can anyone suggest an approach or a solution? Reference link to streams will also be  helpful.

Comment: In `complexList`, which is a `Map`, your values are `Set`s. Obviously, there is only one value per key – it's actually the sets size you are interested in. However, do you really want to start from `complexList`? You could implement this counting directly from `smList`.

Comment: I know I can do it with smList. But, I need to return complexList to calling function and that will do further manipulation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if all you want to do is print each key of the map along with the size of the corresponding value, then there is no need to stream again as it causes unnecessary overhead. simply iterate overly the `complexList` and print it like so:

```
complexList.forEach((k,v)->System.out.println(k+"="+v.size()));
```

or if you *really* want a map then one could also do:

```
Map<Float, Integer> accumulator = new HashMap<>();
complexList.forEach((k,v)->accumulator.put(k, v.size()));
```

Comment: Yeah this is the perfect solution to my problem.

Comment: Good example of using forEach instead of Collector.

Answer (score 2):

You are making it very complex. Easier solution below:

```
Map<Float, Long> complexCount = complexList
.entrySet()
.stream()
.collect(Collectors.toMap(
               Map.Entry::getKey,
               entry -> new Long(entry.getValue().size())
        )
);
```

Here, you just need to call `Collectors.toMap`. It has two functions one for key and another for value of the map.

If there is no restriction of using Long as Map value type, then :

```
 Map<Float, Integer> complexCount = complexList
    .entrySet()
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                   Map.Entry::getKey,
                   entry -> entry.getValue().size()
            )
    );
```

Comment: `Entry::getKey` probably instead of the lambda... also you *might* want to add a merge function just in case...

Comment: Tried this solution, compiler says "cannot convert from Map<Object,Object> to Map<Float, Long>. Making it Map<Object,Object> works. Any casting possible?

Comment: Thanks @Eugene for suggestion. nizamuddin, it was a really quick answer for the problem. Let me put a working one there.

Comment: Nizamuddin if you change the size by Integer or if there is a  requirement to get it as Long then use `new Long(entry.getValue().size())`. Updating my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of multiple `Collector`s and `collectingAndThen()`. And don't even need to collect it to an intermediate map:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;

/* ... */

Map<Float, Integer> collect = smList.stream()
    .collect(groupingBy(SomeModel::getCapacity,
        collectingAndThen(
            mapping(SomeModel::getId, toSet()),
            Set::size
        )
    ));
```

Comment: I don't think you can assume that SomeModel#getId is unique, in which case `toList` instead of `toSet`, but may be if the the OP can confirm this...

Comment: @Eugene well I just adapted `toSet()` from OP's question. But your point of course is right

Comment: @Lino I want to take "complexList" instead of "smList"

Comment: @NizamuddinShaikh why though? Are you needing the `complexList` elsewhere too? If not, above approach is probably better than creating `complexList`

Comment: @Lino I did a similar solution to yours `Map<Float, Long> simpleCount = smList.stream().
    collect(Collectors.groupingBy(SomeModel::getCapacity, Collectors.counting()));` which is not what I needed. That's why SO

Comment: @Lino yeah I am returning `complexList` to calling method for further processing.